# Findind the Pseudoinverse of a $2\times 2$-matrix (real-valued)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, svd, pseudoinverse, self-adjoint-operators

As is said in the title I would like to find the pseudoinverse of the real-valued matrix $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

I've never done this before but I looked up some different methods but none worked..

- First I tried the SVD but ended up stuck with an impossible system to find $U$. I used:

$$AA^{\bot} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

Which gave me $\Sigma = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\sqrt{2} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right)$ and $V = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right) = I_2$

By construction we should have

$$A = U\Sigma V^* \implies A = U\Sigma$$ (since $V = I_2$), but such $U$ can't exist, and so I'm stuck..

But I would really like to understand why, is it because $A, A^{\bot}$ or their product didn't fulfill some initial conditions I missed?

- Anyway since it didn't get me where I wanted I tried using the formula: $A^+ = (A^{\bot}A)^{-1}A^{\bot}$, which I believe only requires $A^{\bot}A$ to be inversible. But once more I ended up with a contradiction, since $(A^{\bot}A)^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\1 & - 1\end{array}\right)$ and $A^{\bot} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\0 & 0\end{array}\right)$, giving $A^+$ should be $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right)$, which doesn't satisfy the property (for example) $A = A^+AA^+$.

So if anyone has some time to look it up and just tell me if I missed an important condition to apply those methods, or could give me another one to finish this question myself, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the SVD if you are able to find a full-rank decomposition, in this case
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
When you have such a full-rank decomposition $A=BC$, where $B$ is right-invertible and $C$ is left-invertible, then $A^+=C^+B^+$ and
$$
B^+=(B^TB)^{-1}B^T\qquad C^+=C^T(CC^T)^{-1}
$$
For your case $B^TB=[1]$ and $CC^T=[2]$, so
$$
A^+=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your alternate method @egreg It is not just a shorter method, but it also helped me understand that I should have used $A^+ = A^{\bot}(AA^{\bot})^{-1}$ instead of $A^+ = (A^⊥A)^{−1}A^⊥$ in my second attempt, since $AA^{\bot}$ has  full row rank. So thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Given a rank-one matrix of any dimension
$$\eqalign{
&A = xy^H \quad\;{\rm where}\;
&x\in{\mathbb C}^{m\times 1},\;y\in{\mathbb C}^{n\times 1}
}$$
there is a *closed-form* expression for its Moore-Penrose inverse
$$A^+ = \frac{A^H}{(x^Hx)(y^Hy)}$$
In the current problem, $A$ is obviously a rank-one matrix with
$$\eqalign{
&x = \left(\begin{array}{rr}1\\0\end{array}\right), \quad
&x^Hx = 1 \qquad
&y= \left(\begin{array}{rr}1\\1\end{array}\right), \quad 
&y^Hy = 2 \\
}$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{
A^+ &= \frac{A^H}{(1)(2)} = \frac 12\pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} \\
}$$

Comment: Good to know as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be $U$, not $V$, that is equal to $I_2$ since the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ are the columns of $U$. Instead the eigenvectors of $A^TA$ are the columns of $V$:
$$A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\qquad V=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus
$$A^+=V\Sigma^+U^T=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\\1/2&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help @Parcy Taxel, indeed $U = I_2$, I made an error there. However I don't understand how you found the coefficient $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$ in $V$? Could you tell me that?

Comment: @Rhaena $V$ must be orthogonal, right?

Comment: Of course, so did you solve $V = \frac{1}{k}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & -1\\1 & 1\end{array}\right)$ such that $VV^{\bot} = I_2$ then ?

Comment: @Rhaena In fact I wrote $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ outside the matrix to save typing time. If you computed $V$ from its eigenvector definition yourself you would get the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by "its eigenvector definition"? the fact that the eigenvectors of $A^{\bot}A$ are the columns of $V$? Because I find that those eigenvectors are $(1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$.. (sorry that I don't understand yet)

Comment: I found my result thanks to @egreg's method but I would still really like to understand your answer, I feel like I'm close

Comment: @Rhaena It is merely computation. For a symmetric matrix the eigenspaces can be chosen to have all orthogonal vectors, and since this is $2×2$ this is easy.